# como crear un contador "de segundos" que se muestre en la ventana de juego en pygame

Tags: pygame

Estoy haciendo un juego en pygame y no e podido añadir un contador dentro del juego para
saber a quantos puntos llegas
Alguien me podria dar un ejemplo?

Comment: que has intentado? lee https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida

Answer (score 0):

Podrias usar la función get_ticks de pygame.time, esta función te devuelve los milisegundos asi que tendrías que dividirlo entre mil para que te de los segundos, aqui te muestro un ejemplo:

```
    def display_text(self, surface, text, size, color, pos_x, pos_y):
        font = pygame.font.Font(self.font, size)

        text = font.render(text, True, color)
        rect = text.get_rect()
        rect.midtop = (pos_x, pos_y)

    def draw_text(self):
        self.display_text(self.surface, str(pygame.time.get_ticks()//1000), 14, WHITE, 500, 20)

    def draw(self):
        self.draw_text()
```